# SimPy using logic to choose between one of two or more resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

How do I give a process the option of picking from two or more different resources?

I need to do this as I am simulating maintenance activities as processes, with resources representing shared facilities available to carry out maintenance. Some maintenance activities can only use one type of facility but other maintenance activities are more flexible and have the option of using multiple types of facility.

So in SimPy terms one process only has the option of choosing a single unique type of resource but other processes can choose from multiple unique types of resource.

Crude explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
resource_A_req = resource_A.request()

resource_B_req = resource_B.request()

yield resource_A_req or resource_B_req
```

Would learning how to use FilterStore be the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield resource_A_req | resource_B_req` might work for you.  You then need to check which request was successful and call `cancel()` on the other one in order to avoid problems (search the docs for "condition events").

`FilterStore` might work, too.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867265/simpy-resource-of-3-where-each-has-different-characteristics/24880803#24880803) for a short example.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I have tried FilterStore with success! I will try the first method you suggest also.